# Start mongodb server on mac

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I'm following along with a MEAN tutorial for PC that says to enter the following command:

```
mongod --dbpath c:\node\nodetest1\data\
```

Since I'm on mac, I tried to type

```
mongod --dbpath /users/[username]/nodetest1/data/
```

I've tried various versions of this (including just mongod, but no matter what, I get:

> mongod: command not found

Everything has been working up to this point.

Comment: How did you install MongoDB? If you haven't installed yet, see: [Install MongoDB on OS X](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/).

Comment: I used the following and it worked. Looks like on Mac, you need the entire file path to run mongo or mongod: /Users/[username]/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.0.7/bin/mongod --dbpath /Users/[username]/nodetest1/data/

Comment: On any O/S, you will need to add the MongoDB bin directory to your `$PATH` environment variable if you don't want to change to the bin directory first or specify the full path to the executables. If you install via a package manager (eg. Homebrew) the MongoDB binaries are normally added to your path by default. It looks like you've installed via a manual download so will also have to add to your path (eg. `echo "PATH=$PATH:~/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.0.7/bin/" >> ~/.bashrc`). That's generally a good idea so you can easily run other tools like the `mongo` shell, `mongodump`, `mongorestore`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please type "echo $PATH" in your terminal and post the path in the question.

After we find the mongod binary we will use the commands below to start mongo.

Won't work yet but putting the code here for later use.

```
mkdir -p /data/db

mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `export MONGO_HOME="<MONGO_INSTALLATION_DIR>"` to your `~/.bashrc`.